# Чем чревато использование entityManager напрямую без участия DAO Слоя?

Tags: java, dao

Чем чревато использование  entityManager  напрямую без участия  DAO Слоя. Некоторые "программисты" не используют DAO и персистят, мержат и селектят напрямую с entityManager. Говоря какой смысл создавать  DAO для простых CRUD операций. На ответ что если поменяется база ответ - просто поменяю ентити менеджер.

Comment: Есть мнение, что entitymanager является одним из вариантов repository. А repository является конкурентом dao. Так что вроде  ничем не чревато.